# Setting a cookie on .github.io domain in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cookies

While on a page on `subdomain.foo.com`, I know it is possible to set a cookie in JavaScript with a `domain=foo.com` clause (or `domain=.foo.com` according to earlier specifications), and have that cookie apply to all subdomains.

When I open up the developer console in Chrome on a GitHub Pages page (say, `yelp.github.io`) and try this using a `domain=github.io` clause, the cookie doesn't get set (`document.cookie` yields the empty string). I only seem to be able to get the cookie to set if I omit the `domain` clause, or use `domain=yelp.github.io`.

I can understand why GitHub would want to restrict cookie scope this way for security reasons, but I'm not sure how this is actually working or what's behind the behavior I'm seeing. Is there something special about the `github.io` domain? Is there a security policy being applied I'm not aware of? Or am I just doing it wrong?

```
document.cookie = 'foo=1; domain=github.io'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [relevant specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.3) (RFC 6265), cookies are rejected for public suffixes if set from a subdomain:

> ```
> If the user agent is configured to reject "public suffixes" and the domain-attribute is a public suffix:
>     If the domain-attribute is identical to the canonicalized request-host:
>         Let the domain-attribute be the empty string.
>     Otherwise:
>         Ignore the cookie entirely and abort these steps.
> ```

> NOTE: A "public suffix" is a domain that is controlled by a
> public registry, such as "com", "co.uk", and "pvt.k12.wy.us".
> This step is essential for preventing attacker.com from
> disrupting the integrity of example.com by setting a cookie
> with a Domain attribute of "com".  Unfortunately, the set of
> public suffixes (also known as "registry controlled domains")
> changes over time.  If feasible, user agents SHOULD use an
> up-to-date public suffix list, such as the one maintained by
> the Mozilla project at http://publicsuffix.org/.

---

`github.io` is on the [public suffix list](https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat).

Comment: What about if they are set from app running on that domain itself and not from sub domain? What does it mean by `Let the domain-attribute be the empty string.`

Comment: Is there a work around to have cookies work on github pages?